# source: unbound variable error when using Cocoapods for Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, google-tag-manager, xcode10.1

I have integrated `Firebase` and `GoogleTagManager` into my iOS app target using Cocoapods.
When I build my target, Xcode constantly gives me error:

```
Showing Recent Messages
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks 

mkdir -p /Users/xxx.xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-enzvpdzsyhjszqbnwiclnpszlyri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Frameworks


/Users/xxx.xxx/Projects/MyApp/Applications/MyApp/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-MyApp-frameworks.sh: line 43: source: unbound variable


Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I've cleaned my project multiple times, deleted the derived data folder but none of these seem to work.

**My Podfile looks like this:**

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyApp' do

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.19'
    pod 'Firebase/ABTesting'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 7.1'
 end
```

**Cocoapods Environment**

```
CocoaPods : 1.5.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.6.8
        Host : Mac OS X 10.14 (18A391)
       Xcode : 10.1 (10B61)
         Git : git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/xxx.xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 7c9a708dce25221eabc35ed39
```

What is it that I am missing in my project settings that is causing this error ?

I have spent several days looking for a solution on SO / Cocoapods but in vain.

Any help in this regards would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: EDIT: CocoaPods : 1.6.1

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8738#issuecomment-489102057

Comment: @PaulBeusterien so do I need to apply the same fix as `${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY:-}` to `"${source:-}" ?`

Comment: The error is suppressed when I replace all occurrences of ${source} with ${source:-} in Pods-Project-frameworks.sh file but the frameworks do not get generated in the `Products` directory in Pods project. @PaulBeusterien any ideas? I desperately need to get this working for my project. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when my framework was built with M1 chip.
I was able to resolve that by removing ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH from the Podfile installer section.

So I replaced this:

```
post_install do |installer|

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

target.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
  config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'

 end
end
```

With this:

```
post_install do |installer|

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

target.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
 end
end
```

*Note: I added ['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO' from the beginning in order to run my app in simulator with the "problematic" framework when the framework was built with non M1 chip.
So I still need this line depending on the chip of the build machine.*

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be some peculiar issue, perhaps bash related or something. For some strange reason, it does not work with ~/Library/.../MyApp-xxxxx.../Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/ directory (Let's call it BUILD_DIR)

If 'source' is undefined, which is the case here, replacing ${source} with ${source:-} does not help because then it places a blank for source, which is not what you want.

For me another problem was rsync does not find the above directory.

Here is what I did:

1. Let the project build and give error. This ensures that the required framework directories are created in my BUILD_DIR, and frameworks are built.
2. Created a directory Pods-frameworks in project root directory, copied all framework directories from BUILD_DIR to this directory.
3. In PodsMyApp-frameworks.sh, last 25 lines, calls to install_framework with all pods-related frameworks in Debug and Release modes, changed ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} to a new macro that is defined to be this new Pods-frameworks directory.
4. Built the projects again.

That solved the problem. If pods is installed again and if there is a version change, this process may have to be repeated.

Comment: you have to remember to repeat this change to  `PodsMyApp-frameworkds.sh` because everytime `pod install` is called this file is regenerated from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I've messed around with this issue for 4 days and finally resolved with a script.

The setup

- RN **0.61.5** upgrading from **0.59.10**
- Xcode **11.3.1**

  - multi-scheme (Staging, Beta)
  - multi-configurations (Staging, Beta)
- CocoaPods **1.9.3**

related npm packages:

```
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^9.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.4.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^7.5.12",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.9.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "6.3.0",
    "react-native-config": "1.4.0"
```

Guides and Sources Used:

- [CodePush Multi Deployment Testing](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/8614337a38806ca55f1ee2731991a088b9c7da04/docs/multi-deployment-testing-ios.md)
- [[iOS] Third-party libraries not found for "staging" config: Solution!](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/426)
   outdated but still used
- [react-native-config#README](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

project 'lend24app',
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Release' => :release,
  'Staging' => :release,
  'Beta' => :release


target 'lend24app' do
  use_frameworks!
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  # Pods for lendmn
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNInputMask', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-text-input-mask/ios/InputMask'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Contacts', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Contacts.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-FaceID', :path => "#{permissions_path}/FaceID.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Reminders', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Reminders.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-StoreKit', :path => "#{permissions_path}/StoreKit.podspec"


  pre_install do |installer|
    installer.analysis_result.specifications.each do |s|
      s.swift_version = '4.0' unless s.swift_version
    end
    # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}

    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
      if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
        def pod.build_type;
          # Uncomment one line depending on your CocoaPods version
          Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.name == 'Staging' || config.name == 'Beta'
        config.build_settings['CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR'] = '$(PROJECT_TEMP_DIR)/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)'
        config.build_settings['CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'] = '$(BUILD_DIR)/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)'
      end
    end
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if config.name == 'Staging' || config.name == 'Beta'
          config.build_settings['CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR'] = '$(PROJECT_TEMP_DIR)/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)'
          config.build_settings['PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'] = '${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  target 'lend24appTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end
```

**This setup is outcome of gradual development of a project since 2016, so the items and actual configurations are not recommended, it's better to start from scrath!**

Steps that lead to this issue, all steps fail to produce beta archive:

1. upgrade rn through upgrade command
2. patch up files missed through the command using [RN Upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/)
3. create Xcode configurations using above mentioned [guide](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/8614337a38806ca55f1ee2731991a088b9c7da04/docs/multi-deployment-testing-ios.md) from Code Push
4. unknown ...

somewhere along the journey I ended up with `PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` Build Setting that has `${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)` for Beta `configuration`

at this point Running `Beta` build, but archiving fails with `source: unbound variable`

whenever I change `PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` to `${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)` or if I edit out the `Podfile` fix for same `PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` change the build stage fails with

```
'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found.
```

Digging through `...frameworks.sh` it is clear that Pods build is outputted to `Release-iphoneos` folder while the rest is in `Beta-iphoneos` due to the `PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` setting or something similar, I've tried changing to default values, but then builds fail even before reaching this Build Phase `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`

in the end I just moved everything from `Release-iphoneos` to `Beta-iphoneos` prior this phase using the following script:

`+ New Run Script Phase`

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]]; then
    exit 0
elif [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

mv $BUILD_DIR/Release$EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME/* $BUILD_DIR/$CONFIGURATION$EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME/
```

Kinda tired here, just thought it might help anyone in similar situation, wish I could help more, feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think is related to c++ version that the framework uses.
for me changing the framework build settings from
`GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu17;`
to
`GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu11;`
resolved the issue.